# SSAS cube restoration / processing - partition issue when restored from server A to server B

Tags: sql-server, ssas, cube, msbi

**Issue Background :**

As part of our environment migration process, we are trying to migrate one of our cubes from our source environment server **A** to destination environment server **B**.

There are partitions defined at source server which refers to location: **I:\XYZ**.

Please note that Cube back up[*.abf file*] from server **A** to server **B** has been successfully restored. But while processing the cube at server **B** it displays the following error -

> 42 Errors in metadata manager. The **I:\XYZ** storage location of the
>   Vw All Up Fact XYZ AllUp partition  does not exist, is too long, or
>   contains characters that are not valid or reserved.

We tried to add a folder in the **I** drive of the destination server **B** which had solved the issue.

**Question:**
Though we had solved the issue in that way in our server **B**, we now have to move to server **C** where we do not have an **I** drive and we cannot expect to have **I** drive everywhere we move our cube.

We tried scripting out the cube and searching for **I:\** where-in-which we found nothing.

Is there a way where we can change that partition reference in the destination server, after restoration ?

Many Thanks. Lakshman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you will be able to change the storage location after you migrate the cube, and before you process it.

One way to do this is to go to the Cube object in BIDS, open the Partitions tab, and edit the Storage Location field in the GUI for each partition.

Another way is in the script, and you must have done something wrong in searching the script for "I:\" because I am able to find it in my Create scripts.   It's in the StorageLocation node under each MeasureGroup node.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, we've now edited the same from GUI. We are trying with scripts and we'll update you. Appreciate your help.